# Stylus throw me an expected "indent", got "outdent", but i have no idea why

Tags: indentation, stylus, parse-error

it's weird i just make a changes in the variable settings to use hashes instead... you know:

```
black = #000
```

is replaced by:

```
colors = {
    'black': #000
     // and so on...
}
```

Then, i replace all variable call's in the code (ofcourse) and all modules compile well, except one, this is the trace:

```
ParseError: ../../dopamine/components/_ui.styl:26
   22|     notice(clr: -colors['light-blue'])
   23|     color -colors['white']
   24|     font-weight bold
   25|     text-shadow 1px 1px 1px rgba(#000, .2)
 > 26|   
   27|   if type == "success"
   28|     notice(clr: -colors['green'])
   29|     color -colors['white']

expected "indent", got "outdent"

    at Parser.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:230:11)
    at Parser.expect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:258:12)
    at Parser.block (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:741:12)
    at Parser.selector (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1277:24)
    at Parser.property (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1228:47)
    at Parser.ident (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1183:25)
    at Parser.stmt (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:685:26)
    at Parser.statement (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:593:21)
    at Parser.block (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:753:21)
    at Parser [as if] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:842:23)
```

So, i checked the basic common typing errors and another things, but i don't get the problem... in the last version did work, and i just changed the variables, i did not touch anything more. The code are in the following links:

[error module](https://github.com/nanotime/dopamine/blob/testing/components/_ui.styl)
[variable settings](https://github.com/nanotime/dopamine/blob/testing/settings.styl)

So, thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, when using hashes as values you also need to use colons. So, instead of

```
.best-thing-ever
  width 1234px
  color colors['white']
  font-size 23px
```

you would write

```
.best-thing-ever
  width 1234px
  color: colors['white']
  font-size 23px
```

Note that the colon is only needed for properties that have hashes as values. See [this related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/issues/1405) for details.